# create plugin from polls application

Tags: django, django-cms, django-apps

I installed app Polls from with `pip install -e git+http://git@github.com/divio/django-polls.git#egg=polls`from. Application is saved `/me/env/src/polls/` . I run server from `/me/project/`. I get an error Poll Plugin cant be imported. How can i define that Polls app use own models.

Now I want to create plugin and placeholder in my template.

```
cms_plugins.py

    from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
    from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
    from polls.models import PollPlugin as PollPluginModel
    from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

    class PollPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
        model = PollPluginModel # <--not sure what to put here.
        name = _("Poll Plugin") # Name of the plugin
        render_template = "polls/plugin.html" # 

        def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
            context.update({'instance':instance})
            return context

    plugin_pool.register_plugin(PollPlugin) # register the plugin
```

polls/models.py

```
class Poll(models.Model):
        question = models.CharField(max_length=200)

        def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
            return self.question


class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to add new app.

Define PollPluginModel and link it with poll
polls/models
    from django.db import models
    from cms.models import CMSPlugin
    from polls.models import Poll

```
class PollPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.poll.question
```

Please check http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/introduction/plugins.html .Here is complete tutorial for plugin.